# Football (Soccer) player physical data (weight and height) over time

Tags: medical, football

Is there any open dataset of physical data (e.g. weight and height) of elite football players in european leagues over time (the last 15 years)?

Comment: Do you want the weight changes of *individual* players throughout their careers, or the *average* weight of players (e.g. per team and season) through the last 15 years?. The European Soccer Database gives you only 1 data point /weight per player

Answer (score 1):

## European Soccer Database

There is an amazing collection of soccer data published openly at Kaggle -- [European Soccer Database](https://www.kaggle.com/hugomathien/soccer).
Make sure you check the diverse examples of analysis of this dataset -- the so called [kernels](https://www.kaggle.com/hugomathien/soccer/kernels).

From the data source description:

> What you get:
>
> - +25,000 matches
> - +10,000 players 11 European Countries with their lead championship
> - Seasons 2008 to 2016
> - Players and Teams' attributes* sourced from    EA Sports' FIFA video    game series, including the weekly updates
> - Team lineup with squad formation (X, Y coordinates)
> - Betting odds from up to 10 providers
> - Detailed match events (goal types,    possession, corner, cross,    fouls, cards etc...) for +10,000 matches

---

## IIHF ice-hockey players height

In case you need just elite sportsmen, here is a small dataset that I gathered manually -- Ice hockey players at IIHF world championships, 2001-2016.

https://dx.doi.org/10.6084/m9.figshare.3394735.v2

The dataset contains 6292 records of 3333 players' height and weight parameters at 16 world championships.

There is also a blog post with some analysis of this dataset
https://ikashnitsky.github.io/2017/ice-hockey-players-height/

This post is also available [in Russian](https://habrahabr.ru/post/301340/).